# Click only on child element

Tags: angularjs

I made a directive that I insert it in the div parent to restrict some things (such restrictions that I do not put in the example), but I also want to listen when you click on the second element only in the second element, how can I listen when you click?

note: I just want to insert in div father the directive

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.on('click', function() {
            console.log('click');
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div click-me>
    clickeame
    <div id="one">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no experience with angularjs, but with most event listeners you can determine the target https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target . you can then check if the event target has the id "one"

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGzBQm

Comment: @YusafKhaliq there's no other way with angular?

Comment: I couldn't tell you sorry (no angular experience). but yes, it would be best to figure out how to do it with without checking each time. my solution is more of a workaround.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your directive as follows,

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.on('click', function(event) {
            if (event.target.id == "one") {
              console.log('click');
            }
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular
  .module('DemoApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.on('click', function(event) {
            if (event.target.id == "one") {
              console.log('click');
            }
          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="DemoApp">
  <div click-me>
    clickeame
    <div id="one">
      click 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's no other way with angular?

Comment: what do you mean by no other way? this is angularjs only

Answer (score 2):

This would be an alternative way to add the event listener to only the child
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGzBQm

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .directive(
    'clickMe',
    function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          element.find("div").on('click', function(event) {
              console.log('click');

          });
        },
      };
    }
  );
```